# How to build an Object from XML, modify, then write to File in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, hash

I'm having an awful time trying to use a library to parse an XML File into a hash like object, modify it, then print it back out to another XML file in Ruby.  For a class I'm taking, we're supposed to use a Java JAXB like library where we convert XML into an object.  We've already done SAX and DOM methods so we can't use those methods of XML de-serialization.  Nokogiri helped me with both of these in Ruby.

The only problem is that besides the SIMPLE modifications I'm making to the objects, when I write to file it has drastic differences.  Is there a Ruby library meant for doing just this?  I've tried: ROXML, XML::Mapping, and ActiveSupport::CoreExt.  The only one I can get to even run is ActiveSupport, and even then it starts putting element attributes as child elements in the output XML.

I'm willing to try out XmlSimple, but I'm curious has anyone actually had to do this before/run into the same problems?  Again, I can't read in lines one at a time like SAX or build a Tree like structure like DOM, it needs to be a hash like object.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify your question/needs? What source data do you have, and what are you trying to get? What code have you tried so far, and what are the errors or incorrect output problems you saw? And are there any libraries or technologies you cannot use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working.  After looking at ActiveSupport::CoreExt 's source code I found it just uses a gem called xml-simple.  What's obnoxious is the gem, library name in the require statement, and class name are a mixture of hyphenated and non hyphenated spellings.  For future reference here's what I did:

```
# gem install xml-simple
#             ^ all lowercase, hyphenated
require 'xmlsimple'
#        ^ all lowercase, not hyphenated
doc = XmlSimple.xml_in 'hw3.xml', 'KeepRoot' => true
#     ^ Camel cased (it's a class), not hyphenated
# doc.class => Hash
# manipulate doc as a hash
file = File.new('HW3a.xml', 'w')
file.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n")
file.write(XmlSimple.xml_out doc, 'KeepRoot' => true)
```

I hope this helps someone.  Also make sure you pay attention to case and hyphens with this gem!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look into nokogiri: http://nokogiri.org/

Then you can parse the XML like this :

```
xml_file = "some_path"
@xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.open xml_file)
@xml.xpath('//listing').each do |node| 
  style  = node.search("style").text
end
```

With Xpath, you can perform queries in the XML :

```
@xml.xpath("//listing[name='John']").first(10)
```

Comment: Sorry, this method of using nokogiri builds a tree like structure (DOM), which I mentioned I can't use.
"We've already done SAX and DOM methods so we can't use those methods of XML de-serialization. Nokogiri helped me with both of these in Ruby."